# Swift initialization from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I am a swift language beginner and I have a question about class initialization.

When you start a new project with a empty ViewController like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
 }
```

Since the `ViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and it has a designated initializer `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)`. When you run the code, "who" is putting in the arguments into the initializer? is it the storyboard?

If that is the case, then if I have a stored property in the my `ViewController` that requires a designated initializer to initialize my stored property, this will of cause break the initialization up the chain, does that mean the storyboard is not longer obligated to initialize the `ViewController` for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is misleading for a beginner, but the initializer is **not** called by anyone in this case. The `ViewController` instance you talk about is *in* the storyboard file, which results in an initialization path I will go into in a second. The method you mention is meant to be used if you *programmatically* create a `ViewController` elsewhere and assign it a specific nib from your application bundle to work with.

The various templates all rely on the application process that is, ultimately, done by the runtime system when launching an app:
When the app launches, it looks into its `Info.plist` to figure out what storyboard to initially load. In the various Xcode templates that's usually `Main.storyboard` (which then specifies an initial view controller of type `ViewController`). Your project will not have anything like "generated code" that does this, since it is the `Application` object that does this. In Objective-C projects you could actually see this, as the entry point was a regular old `main` method (in `main.m`). The Swift runtime doesn't show this, it's part of the linked framework your app uses.

So much for that, now it is important to understand how storyboards (and xib files for that matter) work:
They are *not* something like "recipes" for the app to create the various objects using the regular designated initializers. They contain actually **already** created objects in a serialized form. That means when you **compile** your app, the `ViewController` is created and archived "away" into the storyboard/xib. At this point, it can't know about the various connections to other objects in the storyboard/xib, because it is **in the process of building said storyboard** (which is why you can't do something meaningful with outlets in `init`, these objects are not yet necessarily created).
Only once this creation and archiving is done, the various connections are (also) saved/added into the storyboard/xib.

Now if your compiled app is started and the `Main.storyboard` specified in the `Info.plist` is loaded and the app unarchives the initial view controller from it. For this, it doesn't use the `init` method of the `ViewController` you mentioned, but its counterpart `init(coder:)`. After that, it connects the various outlets and actions with the other relevant objects unarchived from the storyboard (or rather, the scene). Then it loads the view, which results in a call of `viewDidLoad`. This also explains why you can only do any relevant intialization to a storyboard-loaded view controller there and not in `init`.

Now, finally, to your question: You simply cannot have a property that relies on the designated initializer of the initial view controller being called during runtime. It simply isn't. This is also the reason most `ViewController` implementations do not override `init`, there's hardly anything meaningful you can do there. You have three options to initialize anything:

1. Override `init(coder:)`. Note that you don't necessarily know which other objects from the Storyboard or scene are unarchived yet and also the connections are not yet made, so you can only do stuff here that doesn't need those.
2. Implement `awakeFromNib`. This is called for any object that is loaded from a xib (and by extension storyboard scene) right after it was unarchived and all its connections to other unarchived objects are made. Note that this won't be the case for `ViewControllers` that are thus not unarchived from a storyboard but instantiated programmatically during runtime. There's some other caveats, too.
3. Initialize everything necessary in `viewDidLoad`. This is only called when the `ViewController`'s view will actually be loaded (i.e. usually when it's about to be displayed), but that is always eventually the case for it I guess. Usually I go with this.

If you find yourself in some circumstance where you have to initialize something in the designated initializer and wonder why it is missing when your view controller is loaded from a storyboard, don't forget to do whatever you do in `init` in `init(coder:)` and potentially in `encode(encoder:)`, too. I rarely had cases like this. To offer a more detailed explanation of when and how this is done I'd need more info from you in terms of what you believe to be necessarily done in `init`. On the top of my head I can come up with custom views (not view controllers) that are added to a storyboard scene, but this answer is long enough already...

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Funny side story: As I was laying in bed yesterday I suddenly thought: "Wait, maybe that changed in swift somehow? Are you **sure** the VC is unarchived with `init(coder:)`? Views in a xib and by extension a scene are, but theoretically the VC could be instantiated using the regular init and only its scene objects unarchived... Did you by chance write a huge answer to a beginner that was *wrong*?" I fretted over this and almost couldn't sleep. This morning I rushed into my office and checked the documentation and, oh sweet relief, I didn't eff up! :D You're very welcome!

Comment: Hey Gero, I really like the style of your answer, easy to read and straight to the point, are you able to answer my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897883/how-to-make-uibuttons-from-a-tree-data-structure-in-swift

Comment: Hi Gero, once again thank you for this piece of information, definitely filled in the missing puzzle for me. One thing I am struggling to understand is what exactly is a bundle? From what I read, bundle is a structure the holds code and frameworks together, but why do we need it in our `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` method? can you please elaborate more on this? thanks

Comment: This might be a little too complex to explain in a comment, but I don't know if it warrants a question either (didn't check whether there are any already). It's basically in the docs *in principle*, but I see why this confuses you. Shortly said the term "bundle" is not strictly defined and used more colloquially. It can refer to any group of files that are literally *bundled together*. The app bundle, e.g. contains the resources for an app and the executable. .framework files are bundles holding binaries, version info files, and headers, etc.

Comment: Since comments are "not for extended discussions" I'd suggest to "move this to chat", I actually just created a [room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149806/geros-help-center) for these kinds of things (cause it sometimes happens people want to discuss stuff like this directly). Downside is that you'd need 20 reputation, but that shouldn't be too hard to get somehow? (Chatrooms don't require you to be on at the same time, btw). You can join now, but only read I think. Maybe you want to give it a try.