# How to make UIButtons from a tree data structure in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tree data structure and want to use that tree structure to generate buttons that segues to it's children programmatically with a new view controller, just like in Apple's setting menu where you have different options and when you tap on a random parent, it will segue to it's children.

```
    class OptionNode{
    var value: String

    weak var parent: OptionNode?
    var children = [OptionNode]()

    init(value: String){
        self.value = value
    }

    func addOption(node: OptionNode){
        children.append(node)
        node.parent = self
    }
}

struct MenuStructure {

static var menuOptions: OptionNode {

    let mainMenu = OptionNode(value: "Main Menu")
    let vehicle = OptionNode(value: "vehicle Menu")
    let food = OptionNode(value: "Food Menu")
    let computer = OptionNode(value: "Computer Menu")

    let ford = OptionNode(value: "Ford Menu")
    let toyota = OptionNode(value: "Toyota Menu")
    let honda = OptionNode(value: "Honda Menu")

    let apple = OptionNode(value: "Apple Menu")
    let orange = OptionNode(value: "Orange Menu")
    let pear = OptionNode(value: "Pear Menu")

    let hp = OptionNode(value: "HP Menu")
    let chrome = OptionNode(value: "Chrome Menu")
    let samsung = OptionNode(value: "Samsung Menu")

    mainMenu.addOption(node: vehicle)
    mainMenu.addOption(node: food)
    mainMenu.addOption(node: computer)

    vehicle.addOption(node: ford)
    vehicle.addOption(node: toyota)
    vehicle.addOption(node: honda)

    food.addOption(node: apple)
    food.addOption(node: orange)
    food.addOption(node: pear)

    computer.addOption(node: hp)
    computer.addOption(node: chrome)
    computer.addOption(node: samsung)

    return mainMenu

    }
}
```

So the first portion of the code is to establish my tree data structure and the rest of the code is to populate my tree structure with node defined previously. This would be separate from the viewController because this is the model layer of the MVC. Then, with that tree structure, I want to add buttons programmatically that represents the tree structure. So for example, the first page would have three buttons namely, "Vehicle", "Food, and "Computer" and when user taps on say the Food button, the screen will segue to a new view controller with another set of buttons, namely "Apple", "Orange", and "Pear". hope this makes sense, thanks!

Thank you

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you intend to accomplish here, I assume the tree structure is somehow created before the first view controller is populated and then each level of the tree has its own view controller, right? I am a little short on time atm, but will try to look further into it either tomorrow afternoon or on the weekend. It would help me if you specified a little about the app's setup as a whole, especially what different view controllers handle the various levels?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have made some changes to the question, thanks!

Comment: To fully explain the various aspects of this I need some time, but will try to do that either tonight or tomorrow. I'll give you a sample project illustrating this, as that makes it the easiest to explain. :)

Comment: Awesome, hey thanks for taking your time and look into this for me, much appreciated!

Comment: Did my answer below help you out or is anything still unclear?

Comment: Hi Gero, I trying my best to understand the code, right now I think I do but there are parts i'm sort of confused, thank you for this in-depth explanation, much much appreciated!

Comment: Great! I know it's tough to get into someone else's code, especially if you are relatively new to a language. If you have any more specific questions we can also start a chat here or you post an issue in the git repo or something (so we don't clutter this Q&A with non-general stuff).

Comment: Yea, I need to crunch through the logic line by line, but I think I understand the concept, thanks for the great explanation and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as promised I wrote a demo project that hopefully helps you understand how this can work. I simply included your demo data so you can better follow: https://github.com/GeroHerkenrath/SOExDynamicButtonGen

To provide an explanation here on SO (and make this a useful answer independent from my demo), some general things:

If I understand you correctly the idea is to completely dynamically determine what view controller to show for a given node. I.e. you click a button, a then decided scene shows the children and if they are clicked, a new scene appears and so forth.

I say scene, because that's mostly what happens, though the important part is actually the view controller. To the user, both might be visible, like in the master detail view on an iPad (on the iPhone it's basically two table view controllers showing individually). I'm just mentioning this because you referred to the Settings app yourself, which is basically a Master/Detail view.

---

Now here is the thing:

Since your UI is basically determined during runtime, I would advise against working with scenes and segues. My example project shows this and has some further explanations (which I will add here at the bottom) on why that is. You can use the **storyboard as basically a collection** (like a "repository") **of needed view controllers that you then instantiate via an identifier**. In my example I just demonstrate this using table view controllers (or rather, one that is used repeatedly) and a navigation view controller. Your UI might look different, with container views or said master detail controller. Once you instantiated a view controller you can do whatever is necessary with it (I push it onto the nav stack). This can become complex, but there's endless possibilities and I can't provide a demo for everything. :) The navigation view controller is the simplest example, but an often encountered one, and iPhones rely heavily on it (due to the screen size).

So to form this into a formula of ToDos for you:

1. Create view controllers for the types of nodes in your tree (depending on how you design this). Give them an identifier in the Storyboard, but don't connect them with segues.
2. Prepare a navigation view controller in your general UI. From in that, once you got your tree, instantiate the first of the view controllers (the top level), prepare it with the root node and push it onto the stack.
3. In the code for these controllers, use the node's data to configure the UI as needed. Rely on the children nodes to populate table cells, buttons etc.
4. Again in the controllers, in the part that handles the click on an element representing a child (cells in my examples), instantiate a new view controller as needed, just like you did in the beginning of your navigation controller's stack. Populate it with the selected child's data and subchildren. Push that.

As said, if you're not using a navigation view controller you have to do whatever else you need (embed it in the container view or whatever), but I guess somewhere you will have this. Displaying a controller modally might also be an option (i.e. not "pushing on the nav stack", but rather calling `presentViewController` or whatever it was called).

I hope this could help you understand the intricacies of the UI a little, feel free to pull my github project and play around in it.
Also read the readme, I explain what exactly I do in there.

---

Lastly, I will copy the section of my readme here that I think is a valuable tip for everyone here on SO new to iOS as well:

> ### General notes on storyboard design & dynamic decisions about scene transitions
>
> There's a lot you can do with storyboards and even without them (I didn't even go into using plain old xibs when instantiating view controllers). However, that doesn't mean you *should* do everything. 
>   Personally, I always took their name quite literally. I want my storyboards to help understand the program's UI-flow when I look at them. 
>   A segue is automatic as much as it is possible in my storyboards. 
>   Once I even added a segue that I didn't use just to make clear that there would be a transition from here to there (the overhead is tiny, as it is just a small entry in the storyboard and would never do anything).
>
> If I want to have "utility" scenes/view controllers that I instantiate from code I make that clear (sadly, I can't add comments to storyboards, that would be neato IMO), for example I group them, maybe even use a different storyboard, or I go with the xib solution in the first place.
>
> It is important to consider readability of the entire project, and carelessly mixing instantiation via identifiers and regular segues transitions can lead to confusion down the road and hard to track down bugs.
>   In this example project, in `DynamicLevelController`'s `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` I provided an example of what not to do in my opinion.
>
> I have encountered projects with code like this, which directly results in the storyboard being misleading:
>   The Storyboard looks like there's a certain path the scenes go with a single "floating" scene you might at first think is a utility that can be accessed from anywhere.
>   The code in this utility controller then all of a sudden leads to a random point in what originally looked like a regular, nice path of scenes.
>   To figure that out you have to look into several places in code, compare identifiers and so forth. That's not helpful.
>
> There might be cases, as always, when you need to do something like this, but if there's no real need to do so, then don't.